# How to add names to more than 1000 columns after reading ascii file into R?

Tags: r, ascii

I have an ascii file with more than 1000 variables, which does not have the column name. The information of column name and column width is stored in a separated table.

After using read.csv importing the ascii file into R, how can I add the more than 1000 column names easily? Thanks.

Comment: `colnames(...) <- ...`

Comment: This question probably too broad as you don't provide any context as to the names desired for example.

Comment: Each column has a certain name, which is stored in a separated file. For instance, the first column name is "name" with a width of 4, second one is "sex" with a width of 2, third one is "education" with a width of 6...

Comment: Thanks jogo. But I am looking for a easy way to do it, instead of listing all the more than 1000 column names there. Any other thoughts?

Comment: What do you want the colnames to be? X1, X2, ..., X1000 ?

Comment: Each column has a certain name, which is stored in a separated file. For instance, the first column name is "name" with a width of 4, second one is "sex" with a width of 2, third one is "education" with a width of 6...